# Page freezes after calling print function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using `window.print()` function to print the content of a `div` but the entire page freezes when I call the print function. Please see code below:

```
render(){
  return(
   <div>
    <div className='style' id='divToPrint'>
     <p>Content to print here.</p>
     <p>Content to print here.</p>
     <p>Content to print here.</p>
   </div>
    <button className='someStyle' onClick={() => printDiv('divToPrint')}>Print</button
    <button className='someStyle' onClick={this.somethingElse}>Something Else
</button>
  </div>
 )
}
```

Print Function:

```
function printDiv(divName) {
  let printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
  let originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;

  document.body.innerHTML = printContents;

  window.print();

  document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
}
```

After printing and calling `document.body.innerHTML = originalContents`, I'm not able to do anything else until I refresh the page. The entire page just freezes.

I'm I missing something?

Comment: We're you ever able to solve this? Because I'm running into the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the content in `state` or get them in `props` and display them

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
state = {
  content:''
}
printDiv = (content) => {
  this.setState({content})
}
render() {
  const {content} = this.state;
  return (
   <div>
    <p>{content}</p>
    <button className='someStyle' onClick={() => printDiv('divToPrint')}>Print</button>
   </div>
 )
}
```